# Different position of element on mobile device than on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have lately been experimenting with jQuery and made sort of a popupmenu.
The position of the popup div is calculated when I show it or when the windows resizes.

I noticed that de positioning doesn't work correctly on mobile devices and the popup div is shown too much to the right.

Why is this popup div shown differently on mobile devices than on a desktop?

Below is a working example which works fine on a desktop pc and here are 2 images that show what goes wrong on a mobile device:

[image: wrong position of popup div]
[image: wrong position of popup div]

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".button").mouseover(function () {
                    showPopup();
                });
        
                var timeout;
                $(".popup").mouseleave(function () {
                    timeout = setTimeout(function () {hidePopup(500);}, 500);                    
                });
                
                $(".popup").mouseenter(function () {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);                   
                });
                
                $(".button").click(function () {
                    togglePopup();
                });
                
                $(".closebutton").click(function () {
                    hidePopup(0);
                });
                
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    positionPopup();
                });
                                
            });
            
            function positionPopup() {
                var pos = $(".button").offset();
                var h = $(".button").height();
                var w = $(".button").width();
                
                var widthPopUp = $(".popup").width();
                var heightPopUp = $(".popup").height();
                
                $(".popup").css({left: pos.left -  widthPopUp - 20 - 3 + w, top: pos.top + h + 10});         
            }
            
            function showPopup() {
                positionPopup();
                $(".popup").fadeIn(300);
            }
            
            function hidePopup(delay) {
                if (typeof(delay) === 'undefined') {
                    delay = 1000;
                }
                $(".popup").fadeOut(delay);
            }
            
            function togglePopup() {
                positionPopup();
                $(".popup").toggle();
            }
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.buttonholder {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3px;
    display: block;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup{
    border: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.closebtnholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.closebutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.popup::after {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 184px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
     </head>
     
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="buttonholder">
                <div class="button">[?]</div>
            </div>
            
            Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard 
            proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters 
            nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen 
            overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 
            populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk 
            door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="closebtnholder">
                <div class="closebutton">[x]</div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://google.be">google</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="triangle">
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query to your css like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
   .container {
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/rh6w934n/

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to fix this.  You can use a responsive css framework such as twitter bootstrap or you can create a new style sheet to overwrite your current one when it is a mobile device.

Kinda like this using PHP:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
<?php
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od|ad)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry|tablet'.
    '|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.
    '|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
if($isMobile){ ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mobile.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

Then in your mobile.css, put your styling for your mobile pages.

```
.container {
width: 300px;  //this will overwrite your old one
}
```

Just to clarify, this is a simple fix but I highly suggest learning a responsive framework.  It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little adjustment to your snippet

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").mouseover(function () {
   showPopup();
  });

  var timeout;
  $(".popup").mouseleave(function () {
   timeout = setTimeout(function () {hidePopup(500);}, 500);                    
  });
  
  $(".popup").mouseenter(function () {
   clearTimeout(timeout);                   
  });
  
  $(".button").click(function () {
   togglePopup();
  });
  
  $(".closebutton").click(function () {
   hidePopup(0);
  });     
 });

 function showPopup() {
  $(".popup").fadeIn(300);
 }

 function hidePopup(delay) {
  if (typeof(delay) === 'undefined') {
   delay = 1000;
  }
  $(".popup").fadeOut(delay);
 }

 function togglePopup() {
  $(".popup").toggle();
 }
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 540px) {
 .container {
  width: 500px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 539px) {
 .container {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 20px auto;
 }
}

.buttonholder {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3px;
    display: block;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup{
    border: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.closebtnholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.closebutton {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.popup {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2em;
 right: 0;
}
.popup::after {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 184px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="buttonholder">
   <div class="button">[?]</div>
  </div>
  
  Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard 
  proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters 
  nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen 
  overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 
  populair geworden met de introductie van Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passages en meer recentelijk 
  door desktop publishing software zoals Aldus PageMaker die versies van Lorem Ipsum bevatten.
  
  <div class="popup">
   <div class="closebtnholder">
    <div class="closebutton">[x]</div>
   </div>
   <a href="http://google.be">google</a>
  </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for making it more responsive but I still have the same problem when zooming on to the questionmark en clicking on it. Any ideas how to fix this?